# FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `unreachable_cookbook?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, berkshelf, berksfile

I am new to chef and started writing a simple recipe using the Users library.  My Berksfile:

```
name@name:~/chef-repo$ cat Berksfile
site :opscode

cookbook "users"
```

and then I ran:

```
berks install
```

and my cookbooks:

```
name@name:~/chef-repo$ ls cookbooks/
users
```

finally my recipe:

```
name@name:~/chef-repo$ cat blah-users.rb 
include_recipe "users"

users_manage "blah-dev" do
  group_id 1001
  action [ :remove, :create ]
end
```

when I appply I get an error:

```
name@name:~/chef-repo$ chef-apply blah-users.rb 
[2015-05-04T09:05:48-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/name/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-05-04T09:05:48-04:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `unreachable_cookbook?' for nil:NilClass
```

I am fairly certain that the **include_recipe "users"** is the problem (at least the first).  I also find this line *Stacktrace dumped to /home/name/.chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out* interesting as there isn't a file at that location.

I have tried with and without sudo.  So I don't think it is a permissions issue.

I am running a local install of chef server 12.3 which looks to be functioning fine...

Thanks

---

```
~/chef-repo$ sudo chef-apply blah-users.rb -l debug

[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: Building node object for tbrown
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: Platform is ubuntu version 14.04
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] INFO: Run List is []
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] INFO: Run List expands to []
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: Loading Recipe users via include_recipe
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] DEBUG: NoMethodError: undefined method `unreachable_cookbook?' for nil:NilClass
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:257:in `unreachable_cookbook?'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:155:in `load_recipe'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:142:in `block in include_recipe'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:141:in `each'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:141:in `include_recipe'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/dsl/include_recipe.rb:26:in `include_recipe'
blah-users.rb:1:in `run_chef_recipe'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/apply.rb:168:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/apply.rb:168:in `run_chef_recipe'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/apply.rb:180:in `run_application'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/apply.rb:193:in `run'
/opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-apply:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-apply:51:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-apply:51:in `<main>'
[2015-05-04T13:17:50-04:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `unreachable_cookbook?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: May you try with `chef-apply blah-users.rb -l debug`. At all I'm unsure chef-apply could be used with dependency (i.e require recipe from another cookbook) as it is intended to run small portion of internal resources only and there's no cookbook loading (and so no read of `metadata.rb` as there's none). Best workaround I can think of is to use chef-solo or chef-zero (See http://docs.chef.io for exented informations) with a cookbook having the correct dependency in it's `metadata.rb` file.

Comment: the metadata.rb needed a "depends" on the "users" cookbook

Comment: You may want to add that as an answer (and accept it) so that if someone stumbles upon this later, they can find it easily.

Comment: I will - tensibai alluded to the answer in the comment.  I want to give an opportunity for that answer to be formalized and if it is I will accept it, otherwsie I will add it myself.

Comment: If you can wait untill tomorow I'll write a correct answer, I'm at home on phone and it's horrible to link to documentation :)

Comment: NP - I am off and on. I willkeep an eye on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comments:

When using `include_recipe` somewhere, the cookbook hosting this recipe has to be loaded, there's two way to get it loaded:

1. Have it in the runlist
2. Use `depends "cookbook", "version limitation"` in the `metadata.rb` file of the cookbook including the other ([Documentation](http://docs.chef.io/client/cookbook_repo.html#metadata-rb))

Here using `chef-apply` we run a specific recipe and not a runlist so the 1 does not apply and the 2 can't apply, there's no cookbook to load, only a recipe. `Chef-apply` aimed to use the internal chef resources and not LWRP.

The way to use multiples cookbooks is to create a cookbook and have a depend directive in its `metadata.rb` file.

After that you can run this cookbook with `chef-solo` or `chef-zero` specifying a runlist on command line with '`-r` or `-o`, this will allow to load all the needed cookbooks and makes the LWRP from depended cookbooks available.

More extended documentation about chef-client modes (solo and zero are just shortcuts) is available [here](http://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html)

Comment: @akaphenom feel free to comment if I've omitted something, I'll edit as needed

Comment: well definitely needed to put the recipe in the cookbook, upload the recipe and the dependent recipe to the chef server, and then reference the recipe via depends in the metadata.rb  I suspect my patience is  something I need to work on.  I cant stand pages of "hello world" tutorials.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have found the source of this problem.
Chef apply does not instantiate the cookbook_compiler variable in the run context object via the load method (https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/run_context.rb#L157). Therefore the compiler object on this line https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/run_context.rb#L469 is nil. It seems to me that the compiler will need to initialized.

Have opened a ticket here:
https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3914